# Improve performance of SFTP fetch using Windows powershell

Tags: powershell, shell

I have script which is working perfectly but it takes almost 15 minutes to copy 220 (10-14kb) zip files to local directory.
below is the script, anyway to improve it.
Thanks.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process -Force
Import-Module Transferetto
    $SftpClient = Connect-SFTP -Server '124.77.98.211' -Username 'FTDD' -Password 'RRGGTIjhh78'
    $List = Get-SFTPList -SftpClient $SftpClient -Path '/FTDD'
    foreach ($File in $List) {
        Receive-SFTPFile -SftpClient $SftpClient -RemotePath $File.FullName -LocalPath "\\data\file\$($File.Name)"
        Write-Host "file fullname $($File.FullName) and file name is  $($File.Name)" 
    }
    Disconnect-SFTP -SftpClient $SftpClient
```

Comment: This appears to be a custom cmdlet, therefore I would raise a performance issue on its related site: https://github.com/EvotecIT/Transferetto/issues

Comment: Download will only be as fast as your network speed and may be slowed by a virus checker.  Also make sure you download on a fast drive that is not fragmented.